Error in CI Gitlab while running pytest selenium
I have a problem with GitLab CI.
I ran a test that works fine locally on Python 3.12.
After committing the code to GitLab CI, it's not working.
My yaml:
image: python:3.11-alpine

stages:
  - test

auto-test:
  stage: test
  services: 
      - selenium/standalone-chrome:latest
  stage: test
  before_script:
    # Install necessary dependencies
    - pip install webdriver-manager
    - apk add --no-cache bash curl unzip chromium chromium-chromedriver
    - pip install --upgrade pip
    - pip install selenium pytest
    - python3 -V
    - python3 -m pip install pytest
    - python3 -m pip install selenium pytest
    - python3 -m pip install webdriver_manager
    - python3 -m pip install allure-pytest

    # Verify installation
    - chromium-browser --version
    - chromedriver --version

    # Set up virtual environment
    - python -m venv venv
    - . venv/bin/activate

  script:
    - echo "Running Test Script..."
    - pytest login_test.py --maxfail=1 --disable-warnings -q --tb=short
  variables:
    # Set Chrome options for headless execution in CI
    DISPLAY: ":99"
    CHROME_BIN: "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
    CHROME_DRIVER: "/usr/bin/chromedriver"

My test script:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pytest
import time

# Setup Chrome options
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def driver():
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)

    yield driver

    driver.quit()


def test_login(driver):
    driver.get("https://websitexxx/login")

    # Find the username and password fields and fill them in
    email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'login-email')]")
    password = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id, 'login-password')]")

    email.send_keys("xxx")  # Replace with the actual username
    password.send_keys("xxx")  # Replace with the actual password

    # Find and click the login button
    login_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@id='submit-btn']")
    login_button.click()

    # Wait for the login process to complete
    time.sleep(10)

    # Check if login was successful by verifying the page title
    assert "Dashboard" in driver.title, "Title did not contain 'Dashboard'"

The stack trace and error:
==================================== ERRORS ====================================
_________________________ ERROR at setup of test_login _________________________
login_test.py:17: in driver
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py:45: in __init__
    super().__init__(
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py:55: in __init__
    self.service.start()
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:98: in start
    self._start_process(self._path)
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py:208: in _start_process
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:1026: in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
/usr/local/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py:1955: in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
E   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver'
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR login_test.py::test_login - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! stopping after 1 failures !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
1 error in 0.80s
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

I tried many suggested ways to make it work, but I'm still getting the error. Please help.
